# PHP / AJAX: Get web page content every 3 seconds until it changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a web server (www.domain.com) that is pinging a subnet web server (test.domain.com) for displayed information until it changes. I want it to run this check every 3 seconds until the status changes to something besides the waiting message, then I want to display that information in the div.

I'm aware that I'll need AJAX to run this somehow if I want to load the page and then have this run as a script, but I've modified maybe 2 AJAX scripts in my life and have no clue where to go with this one.

The following code is my test base PHP that works for the basic workflow, but it does it all server side.

```
  $str = file_get_contents($url);
  $spanCount = preg_match_all("/\<span id\=\"spanId\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$str,$span);
  $spanString = implode($span[0]);
  echo "<div class='status' style='display:inline;'>";
  while($spanString == "<span id=\"spanId\">Waiting for stuffs...</span>"){
      echo "Waiting...";
      $str = file_get_contents($url);
      $spanCount = preg_match_all("/\<span id\=\"spanId\"\>(.*?)\<\/span\>/",$str,$span);
      $spanString = implode($span[0]);
      sleep(3);
  }
    if($spanString != "<span id=\"spanId\">Waiting for stuffs...</span>"){
      echo "<pre>";
      echo $spanString;
      echo "</pre>";
    }

  echo "</div>";
```

Comment: AJAX won't work for this unless you use CORS, as the domains of the sending/receiving servers are different.

Comment: Information on that? What if I change this to do a curl call every 3 seconds to my other server and have the other server return information via curl?

Comment: I expect I'd try putting an AJAX call, in a setInterval, that executes a script on the same server the current page is loaded from, and that server script does the ping to the other server, and sends a response back to the page.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I don't think that will work for this workflow, as the content will not always push back to www, just when www requests it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the AJAX call need to consume the entire HTML of the web page? If it's a service you control, allowing AJAX to make a GET to your php script and having it return a JSON object of data would make things very simple.

```
get to status.php returns -> {status:"waiting", content: null} //do nothing
get to status.php returns -> {status:"waiting", content: null} //do nothing
get to status.php returns -> {status:"someawesomestate", content: "<blink><marquee>You're our 1,000,000th visitor!</marquee></blink>"} // grab content and update page
```

Using JSONP will allow you very easily to grab the data cross domain if you have issues there. (jQuery powered example)

```
$.getJSON('the/path/status.php').
  .done(function(json) {
    if(json.status != "waiting") {
      $('.some-container').html(json.content);
    }
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    alert('something exploded.');
});
```

Comment: It's actually XML that's being returned in the successful "someawesomestate". plain text that's being displayed in the waiting. I'm going to test out your suggestion!

Comment: if it's not a json response, getJSON will not work! it can be an xml string packed inside of the json response, but for getJSON(p) to work correctly you will definitely need to give the ajax call back a chunk of json

Comment: Yeah I'm going to try to change my test.domain.com to give JSON. (it's written in C# which is new to me, so we'll see). Learning new stuff all day!

Comment: Your example would still be triggered by PHP though, so the page wouldn't fully load until someawesomestate was responded, right?

Comment: the page with a container and default text is delivered to the browser. the browser then polls the server, and when it receives a payload it updates the dom. let me throw together a quick fiddle.

Comment: ok, sloppy and quick mockup. basically this will deliver a static page. the JS sets up an interval that checks the json variable every 3 seconds, and does something with it when it detects the status has changed from "waiting". the manual button click that updates the data will be replaced with the ajax pulling in your data, obviously. http://jsfiddle.net/dc2bar/G3MQA/

Comment: This got me down the right track to where I needed to go, thank you for your help on this one! (project completed and working very well for what I need)

Comment: sweet! happy to help =)